# How to conditional set the id attribute of a HTML element with angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to set the id attribute of a HTML element conditionally.

Simple way:

```
<!--  expression = true -->
<div ng-if="expression"> 
  <a href id="this-one">Anchor with id</a>
</div>
<div ng-if="!expression">
  <a href>Anchor without id</a>
</div>
```

> ```
> output-if-expression-true = <a href id="this-one">Anchor with id</a>
>
> output-if-expression-false= <a href>Anchor without id</a>
> ```

Can I avoid this with something like a ternary operator ? for example ...

```
<a href ng-attr-id="{{expresion ? 'this-one': ''}}">Anchor</a>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Why do you ask if you already know the answer :-)? Try it out, it is indeed

```
<a href ng-attr-id="{{expresion ? 'this-one': ''}}">Anchor</a>
```

Comment: For some reasons I thought it will not compile and get an error (sorry), but it works, well...I also accept other answers :)

Comment: no worries, I bet it's still useful for other people with the same problem

Comment: people like me :) +1

Comment: but now I'm getting Can't bind to 'ng-attr-id' since it isn't a known property of 'ul'

Comment: Not working for me. Which Angular version are you using?

Comment: Here's a plkr with version 1.6.1, also verified with 1.5.4: https://plnkr.co/edit/OKReWXlmCBijDo6l12UR?p=preview

Answer (score 12):

The above solution didn't work for me. The following did:

```
id="{{expression ? 'this-one': 'that-one'}}"
```